# Different array declaration in c while using scanf

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

What is the difference  with

```
  for(i=0;i<j;i++)
  scanf("%d",&a[i]);
```

and

```
for(i=0;i<j;i++)
scanf("%d",a+i);
```

Comment: The two forms are equivalent.  `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`, so `&a[i]` is `&*(a + i)` which is just `a + i`.

Comment: That makes sense a lot.

Comment: there is one significant difference for readers "&a[i]" clearly shows it is a pointer of an array while "a + i" it little more hidden intention; Especially if you are working with macros ie: "#define pointerofarrayelement(a, i) (&a[i])" should be preferred over "+",

Comment: If you really want to confuse people, you can also use `&i[a]`.  This is equivalent to `&a[i]` but very abnormal and misleading, and very bad form.  I do *not* recommend using this in any serious code.  But the `[]` operator is in fact commutative.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.  `&a[i]` is exactly the same as `a+i`.

Section 6.5.2.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the array index operator `[]` states:

> A  postfix  expression  followed  by  an  expression  in  square 
>   brackets `[]` is  a  subscripted designation of an element of an array
>   object.  T**he definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that
>   `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`.** Because of the conversion
>   rules that apply  to  the  binary `+` operator,  if `E1` is  an  array
>   object  (equivalently,  a  pointer  to  the initial  element  of  an 
>   array  object)  and `E2` is  an  integer, `E1[E2]` designates  the
>   `E2`-th element of `E1` (counting from zero).

Comment: I understand. Actually I was trying to make sure about why two forms are equivalent.